# dplyr::arrange with a column of numeric factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I've been at it for an hour now.

DataFrame Looks Like this:

```
> head(cpgval.filtered)
      X        CpG txpt  tss
1 72923 cg15319295 XIST XIST
2 72924 cg03554089 XIST XIST
3 72925 cg12653510 XIST XIST
4 72926 cg05533223 XIST XIST
5 72927 cg11717280 XIST XIST
6 72928 cg20698282 XIST XIST
                                                                                        CellLine      Meth
1 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.8141782
2 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.9349818
3 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.7045790
4 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.9728426
5 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.8467799
6 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged.P103.total.DNA.methylation.RepB 0.8038316
  OrigOrder                                              CultureConditions GroupNumber         corr      PVal
1         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1  0.346066701 0.3616219
2         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1 -0.396517739 0.2907117
3         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1 -0.337107272 0.3750063
4         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1  0.063036561 0.8720074
5         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1 -0.007955937 0.9837932
6         7 hESCs.cultured.on.mouse.feeder.layer.and.mechanically.passaged           1  0.360234098 0.3409356
  Passage
1     103
2     103
3     103
4     103
5     103
6     103
```

Passage Column Consists of 8 Different Numbers:

```
> unique(cpgval.filtered$Passage)
[1] 103 104 147 161 41  42  5   6  
Levels: 103 104 147 161 41 42 5 6
```

I want to arrange the dataframe in passage order 5,6,41,42,103,104,147,161

So, I call:

```
cpgval.filtered <- cpgval.filtered %>% dplyr::arrange(as.numeric(Passage))
```

And I get the same thing as my original dataframe:

```
> unique(cpgval.filtered$Passage)
[1] 103 104 147 161 41  42  5   6  
Levels: 103 104 147 161 41 42 5 6
```

It looks like it is ordering based on the first number and not the number's actual value. WTF?

Comment: `cpgval.filtered$Passage=as.numeric(as.character(cpgval.filtered$Passage))`

Comment: Check out the results of `as.numeric(cpgval.filtered$Passage)` - I think you'll be surprised. Then try `as.numeric(as.character(cpgval.filtered$Passage))`

Comment: Wen's comment worked! Thanks! Can someone explain what happened?

Comment: @AlexNesta - you were working with a `factor` - take a look at `x <- factor(c(1,1,2), levels=1:2, labels=c(100,11))` and note how the values are stored and labelled, and then try `as.numeric(x)` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we tell R to convert a character vector to factor, it assigns factor levels (the underlying numerical representation of the factor) based on alphabetical order. Things get confusing if your character vector represents actual numbers. Consider:

```
factor(1:10)
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

factor(as.character(1:10))
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Note that in the first case, factor levels are assigned as we expect, because the original data are numeric. However, in the second case, the vector being converted are *strings*, where "1" and "10" are "alphabetically" first.

In your case, I'm guessing that the `Passage` column was imported as character data instead of numeric, which in turn was converted to counterintuitive factor levels.